# Semicolon is replaced by %3b in links

Tags: 2013, url, hyperlink

I have a url http://example.com/?q1=abc;q2=123;q3=xyz
When I try to add a link to this url on a SharePoint page the semicolon is replaced by `%3b`.
What can I do to add the correct link?

Comment: are you trying to add it in wiki page, web part pages?

Comment: @KarthikJaganathan It's a default publishing page.

Comment: It's browser encoding of a special character. I don't think you can change it.

Comment: @DanielZiga No, it's not the browser. SharePoint stores the ; as %3b

Answer (score 2):

If the encoding of semicolons is breaking your query string, use ampersands instead. [They are both allowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Web_forms).

Comment: That helps but I have to change a lot of links that I get from an external service.

Comment: How are you getting them? If it's programmatically, surely you could find some function to replace semicolons with ampersands. For example, the XPath translate function could be used right before they get displayed on the SharePoint page.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal encoding and is required to use URLs reliably.

Look at http://www.asciitable.com to see how other characters may be encoded.